# Application in IIS throws 404 page, which is a subfolder within the root folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, http-status-code-404

I have an application deployed at my client server which is Windows 2012 Server with IIS.

Within root folder there is a subfolder where the application is deployed,
which throws 404 error every once in a while, the application sticks to the same error until we restart the IIS server.

Main domain:     *www.domain.com*

Subfolder within domain:  *www.domain.com/subfolder*

The application resides in `subfolder`.

Application built with `Codeigniter`.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Hi, Check the IIS log

Comment: The details are not enough to find the root cause so it is appreciated if you could create failed request tracing rule for 404 error and post the detailed error message. The FRT log can be found in C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles and it can be opened via IE explorer.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis